# How to find which package provides a file?

Tags: package-management, gentoo, dependencies

For example, I can't install package `qcad` because of error: "can't find qdict.h".
How can I find the package which provides the file `qdict.h` so I can install the package `qcad`?

Comment: what package???

Comment: @Joe, I illustrate: I want to install qcad, but it doesn't compile because can't find file `qdict.h`. I want to know which package contains that file. I've tried to google, but found nothing.

Comment: is it an overlay or regular package that you downloaded

Comment: perhaps emerge -av qt

Comment: I've download ebuild, made some error fixes in code and rebuild manifest. QCad is absent in official repos.

Comment: @warl0ck, there's no package `qt`. BTW QCad needs qt3, but there's no qt3 in official packages. I don't understand how it's possible.

Comment: Qt3 is probably available in some overlays

Comment: Thanks to all! I found `app-portage/pfl`: its `e-file` helps me. This is `qt-meta`.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82021/13011

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may use the `e-file` command from the `pfl` package (`emerge -av app-portage/pfl`) to search by package contents.

`e-file YOURFILE`

Alternatively, you may use an [online database](http://www.portagefilelist.de/site/query/file).

Regarding the `qcad` package specifically, you probably need the Qt4 package. IIRC, use `emerge -av x11-libs/qt-gui` (If that doesn't work out, try searching for QT packages.  Use this query: `emerge -s qt`.)

Comment: To be more precise, `pfl` provides the command `e-file`

Comment: FYI, the `e-file` command simply queries the very same online database linked in the answer.  It's called the Portage File List.