# What is the equivalent of apt-file in portage, if any?

Tags: package-management, apt, gentoo, dependencies, funtoo

Hunting for [dependencies](http://xkcd.com/754/) when compiling software from the scratch is practically unavoidable. In [Debian-based Linux distributions](http://www.debian.org/misc/children-distros) which use the [apt-get](http://wiki.debian.org/apt-get) utility to manage packages, there is also a nice command named `apt-file`. One can [use it to search for (missing/wanted) files inside packages](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-search.en.html#s-apt-file) to actually trace the required package(s).

Is there an equivalent functionality in [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/)'s/[Funtoo](http://www.funtoo.org/)'s [portage](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/portage/) system?

Comment: Can't write answer to such an old question (or I might have insufficient rep). If the package isn't installed neither `equery belongs...` nor `qsearch...` works. At least not for me as of 2022.11.30. What worked was grepping `/var/db`, e.g., `grep -nRI "lsusb" /var/db`, then `sys-apps/usbutils` can be inferred from that. It might be useful to someone, who doesn't know a Gentoo way -- i.e., me :) -- if there is any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`emerge pfl && e-file filename`

You need to use the full file name (It also supports full path), it doesn't do partial matches as that would yield too many results; probably to spare bandwidth. For such cases you can indeed resort to running description, eg. eix -S glw or the others mentioned in the other answer.

http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Pfl

Comment: Yep, it does the job!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work always though (and, yet, I have to learn how it works). E.g., `e-file glw` does not return anything, where `qsearch glw` returns `x11-libs/libGLw Mesa GLw library`.

Comment: You need to use the full file name (It also supports full path), it doesn't do partial matches as that would yield too many results; probably to spare bandwidth. For such cases you can indeed resort to running description, eg. `eix -S glw` or the others mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Sometimes hunting for unknown packages, though, does imply that the user does not know what exactly is looking for. I guess it depends on the situation. Anyhow, the important thing is that the tools are there.

Comment: if you don't mind, please add some of your 2nd comment in your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Done, linked to the Gentoo Wiki as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Portage-utils](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/portage-utils.xml) offer a tool, `qsearch`, that does *search the Portage tree (much faster than default `emerge -s`)*.