# How to install PFL (e-file) on Gentoo (in Docker)

Tags: bash, docker, gentoo, emerge

I can't seem to figure out how to install `pfl` in order to get the `e-file` command.

It was mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70401/126773) that the `pfl` package would install the `e-file` command.

So started a Gentoo Docker container and gave it a try:

```
$ docker run -ti gentoo/stage3 bash
$ emerge --sync
...
$ emerge app-portage/pfl
...
$ e-file
bash: e-file: command not found
```

The output mentioned somehting about `use --autounmask-write`, so I tried again:

```
emerge --autounmask-write app-portage/pfl
$ e-file
bash: e-file: command not found
```

The output also mentiond something about `sys-apps/util-linux`, so I installed that too and tried again:

```
$ emerge sys-apps/util-linux
...
$ emerge --autounmask-write app-portage/pfl
...
$ e-file
bash: e-file: command not found
```

I also tried simply running `emerge pfl`:
$ emerge pfl
...
$ e-file
bash: e-file: command not found

Then I started a new bash session and tried again:
$ bash
...
$ emerge --autounmask-write app-portage/pfl
...
$ e-file
bash: e-file: command not found

Nothing seems to work...

It also mentions `IMPORTANT: 5 config files in '/etc/portage' need updating.`. I'm not sure what to make out of this. I just want to install a simple package on a fresh docker container. Surely this shouldn't involve manually changing config files, right?

Full output of `emerge --autounmask-write app-portage/pfl`:

```
 * IMPORTANT: 9 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.


 * IMPORTANT: 4 config files in '/etc/portage' need updating.
 * See the CONFIGURATION FILES and CONFIGURATION FILES UPDATE TOOLS
 * sections of the emerge man page to learn how to update config files.
Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild  N     ] sys-libs/libcap-ng-0.8.2-r1  USE="-python -static-libs" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_9 -python3_8" 
[ebuild   R    ] sys-apps/util-linux-2.36.2-r1  USE="caps*" 
[ebuild  N     ] app-portage/pfl-3.1-r1  USE="network-cron" PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_9 -python3_8" 

The following USE changes are necessary to proceed:
 (see "package.use" in the portage(5) man page for more details)
# required by app-portage/pfl-3.1-r1::gentoo[network-cron]
# required by app-portage/pfl (argument)
>=sys-apps/util-linux-2.36.2-r1 caps

Autounmask changes successfully written.

 * IMPORTANT: 5 config files in '/etc/portage' need updating.
 * See the CONFIGURATION FILES and CONFIGURATION FILES UPDATE TOOLS
 * sections of the emerge man page to learn how to update config files.
```

Content of `/etc/portage`

```
$ tree /etc/portage
/etc/portage
|-- make.conf
|-- make.profile -> ../../var/db/repos/gentoo/profiles/default/linux/amd64/17.1
|-- package.use
|   `-- zz-autounmask
|-- repo.postsync.d
|   `-- example
`-- savedconfig
    `-- sys-apps
        `-- busybox-1.32.1-r1
```

Installing other packages like `emerge app-text/tree` worked just fine btw.

Comment: `/usr/bin/e-file` doesn't exist and `equery f pfl` returns `!!! No installed packages matching 'pfl'`.

Comment: [Discussion archived in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128891/discussion-between-quasimodo-and-forivin).